# Linear regression with zero slope and different intercepts according to factor

Tags: r, lm

I have a data frame like this

```
  head(mydata)
    y         class
  -0.06047565     1
   0.76982251     1
   3.05870831     1
   2.07050839     1
   2.62928774     1
   4.71506499     1
   3.96091621     1
   2.73493877     1
   3.81314715     1
   4.55433803     1
   2.22408180     2
   2.35981383     2
   3.40077145     2
   4.11068272     2
   4.44415887     2
   7.78691314     2
   7.49785048     2
   6.03338284     2
   9.70135590     2
   9.52720859     2
```

where `y` are numeric values and `class` are factors

```
class(mydata$class)
[1] "factor"
```

I would like to perform a linear regression with zero slope and intercept that depends on the class.

However when I do

```
lm(y ~ class,data = mydata)
```

I get this result which I don't understand

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ class, data = mydata)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       class2       class3       class4       class5  
      2.825        2.884        5.001        8.497       10.917
```

Why there is only one intercept? And what are the values for each class, intercepts or slopes?

Many thanks

Comment: To specify zero intercept, use `y~class+0`

Comment: @rmb thanks. The coefficients I get for each class are then slopes?

Comment: Compare the output of `lm(y ~ 0 + class, mydata)` to `with(mydata, tapply(y, class, mean))` to give an idea what is happening.

Comment: @user3910073 yes, those are the slopes.

Comment: @rmb sorry I don't understand then. I would like to have different intercepts for each class and zero slope for each class.

Comment: They represent a different intercept for each level of your class variable. These correspond to the mean of y for each class.

Comment: I think it is worth reading an introduction to  linear regression. There are lots of examples on the web, [UCLA is one](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjABahUKEwj_yIDiwY_IAhWtF9sKHcgsDMU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fscc.stat.ucla.edu%2Fpage_attachments%2F0000%2F0139%2Freg_1.pdf&v6u=https%3A%2F%2Fs-v6exp1-ds.metric.gstatic.com%2Fgen_204%3Fip%3D81.109.228.185%26ts%3D1443092305981526%26auth%3Dcwcgohp6gz76kcz3yuhrwcbcrrlgk3da%26rndm%3D0.121153410985964&v6s=2&v6t=6110&usg=AFQjCNGz7L2xfducPsG8v3tsct-Q5QzrTA)

Answer (score 1):

1. There's only one intercept because the multiple regression model fits a hyperplane, which intersects the y-axis at a single value. In this case the y-axis is where the baseline (or reference) group, class1 sits.
2. The coefficients of the class indicators (dummies) can indeed be seen as slopes.

   If you look at the comparison of class2 with class1 (the base class) then for the comparison of class2=1 vs class2=0, (with other indicators than class1 and class2 set to 0) then the plot of y vs class2 shows a slope that is the coefficient of class2:

   [image]

   Similar relationships can be shown for the other coefficients.

   They can be seen simultaneously as a "difference in groups means" (compared to the baseline) and as a particular slope (again, one giving a comparison to the baseline group).